# Use email with Passport-local. Previous help not working

Tags: javascript, authentication, express, passport.js

So I'm using passport-local and express to handle user log-in. So far I have been able to get a successful log-in while using usernames, but usernames are hard to remember and I personally don't think they should be used for handling users, so I tried modifying the sample Strategy provided on the passport-local page to confirm users via email, but the code doesn't work.

The strategy I have for emails is:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ email: email }, {}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + e }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

And It's derived from this strategy:

```
//The login strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

So the username strategy works perfectly fine, but the email one is not. I even left a console.log() in both the username and email strategy to see what the strategies were returning. The Username strategy returns all information on the user, while the email strategy returns

> false

. I have no idea why the site is doing this, and none of the solutions I've seen so far work.

One solution I've seen on another post suggested that I just use the

```
 findOne({email: email}, function(err, user){
});
```

option to login with the email to find the user, but it hasn't been working at all.

Here is the Jade file I use to take input from the user:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Login

    form(action= '/login', method='post')
        p Email
            br
            input#email(type='text',value='',placeholder='@',name='email')
        p Password
            br
            input#password(type='password',value='',placeholder='Password',name='password') 
        input(type='submit') Submit
```

And here is the POST input:

```
// POST /login
//   This is an alternative implementation that uses a custom callback to
//   acheive the same functionality.
exports.postlogin = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {
      req.session.messages =  [info.message];
      return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

What the heck is going on here? With email it should be working perfectly. Also since I'm asking a question anyway, how do I confirm the email after somebody had registered?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It seems to me you just changed the name of the argument in the LocalStrategy callback to "email". Passport doesn't automagically know that the field is named email though, you have to tell it.

> By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```

[Source](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/)

Comment: I swear there's magic in stackoverflow. For the longest I've tried to work with this issue. I even tried the example you posted before, nothing worked until now. Thank you very much!

Comment: `passwordField` should be `password` imo

Comment: what about a third option? (using username, password and email)

Comment: Dear Andreas!!!! You saved hours and our timeline. Was struggling with solution for last few hours. It worked.!!!

Comment: you sir, are a coding ninja!

Answer (score 9):

If you are new to NestJs and wondering how to achieve the above. You can pass the config options in the `super()` method like this:

```
super({ 
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
})
```

[source](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-local)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition for those who cannot get it to work with the above solution (like me), try this instead:

```js
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (request, username, password, next) => {
      User.findOne({ email: username })
      ...
```

Package versions (as of today):
passport: "^0.4.1",
passport-local: "^1.0.0"

Answer (score -1):

passport is a little bit complicated to understand. I had the same issue, what I did was that on my view (.ejs) instead of naming the input as "email" I just renamed it to "username", since that's what passport is expecting.

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<div class="form-group">
 <input class="form-control" type="email" name="**username**" placeholder="Email" required>
```

Answer (score -1):

passport.use(
new LocalStrategy(
{
usernameField: "email", // Setze das Feld für den Benutzernamen auf 'email'
passwordField: "password", // Setze das Feld für das Passwort auf 'password'
},
async (username, password, cb) => {
// Hier wird 'username' verwendet, es wird jedoch in Wirklichkeit die E-Mail sein
try {
const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email: username }) // Benutze 'username' als E-Mail
.select("+email +password")
.exec();
if (!existingUser || !existingUser.password) {
return cb(null, false);
}
const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
password,
existingUser.password
);
if (!passwordMatch) {
return cb(null, false);
}

```
    const user = existingUser.toObject();
    delete user.password;
    return cb(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    cb(error);
  }
}
```

)
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).