# Getting error [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] while trying to login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I've provided `login/register` system to my page, but I get an error I've been struggling with while trying to `login`:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "salt" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
at check (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:59:10)
at Object.pbkdf2 (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:25:5)
at validPassword (/Users/krzysztofbialk/TO.DO/config/passwordUtils.js:14:29)
at /Users/krzysztofbialk/TO.DO/config/passport_log.js:21:33
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Looks like something here is the problem:

**passwordUtils.js**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
function genPassword(password) {
    let salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    let genHash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return {
      salt: salt,
      hash: genHash
    };
};
function validPassword(password, hash, salt) {
    let hashVerify = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return hash === hashVerify;
};
module.exports.validPassword = validPassword;
module.exports.genPassword = genPassword;
```

or
**passport_log.js**

```
const customFields = {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
    };
    const verifyCallback = (username, password, done) => {
            LogUser.findOne({username: username})
                .then((user) => {
                console.log(user)
                    if (!user) {return done(null, false)}
                    const isValid = validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt);
                    if (isValid) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    done(err);
                });
        };
// LOCAL STRATEGY; it looks good, doesn't it?
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback));
```

**login post route**

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/private', failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

When I console.log(user) it returns

```
{
  _id: 60cbb580ef0690505762a581,
  username: 'qw@wp.pl',
  createdAt: 2021-06-17T20:50:08.570Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

But after successful `register` it returns

```
{
  _id: 60cbb580ef0690505762a581,
  username: 'qw@wp.pl',
  hash: 'b762ebbafb266dab12f71eeabbdae6d53e62e91937c51d99fe1816e6d401379b91495b7db0f56b8143e8607bf72ce2a565c38eeeb1f916cc9c0a85d8e6d3c9fe',
  salt: '0536b806ac052e5628c74e7ec9fd6b94fb0d1bd4bc0e93fdfdf51ed5b964c581',
  createdAt: 2021-06-17T20:50:08.570Z
}
```

And in `DB`:

```
   _id:ObjectId("60cbb580ef0690505762a581")
    username:"qw@wp.pl"
   hash:"b762ebbafb266dab12f71eeabbdae6d53e62e91937c51d99fe1816e6d401379b91495b..."
   salt:"0536b806ac052e5628c74e7ec9fd6b94fb0d1bd4bc0e93fdfdf51ed5b964c581"
    createdAt:2021-06-17T20:50:08.570+00:00
    __v:0
```

Why there is hash and salt in user data after `register`, but not when tried to `login`?

`LogUser` schema:

```
const LogUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String    
},
email: {
    type: String,
    // required: true,
    // unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
},
image: {
    type: String
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
hash: {
    type: String
},
salt: {
    type: String
}});
```

I have ran out of ideas what's wrong.
Happy to receive any answers!

Comment: console.log( user.salt) before calling validPassword

Comment: @TusharShahi, returns undefined. How and where can I convert it to string?

Comment: If you want it in your DB, you have to ensure you are saving something in your salt field when you are saving your object.

Comment: Salt field as well as hash field are saved in my DB and the fields are not empty, they are saved correctly. It just looks like it's not fetched correctly from DB.

Comment: While console.log(newUser) when registering one, all the data showed up and there was no problem to save it in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing to show what turned out to be the right answer:

I think Mongoose removes the hash and salt fields from these kinds of queries by default. So to make your query work you just need to type `LogUser.findOne({username: username}, 'username salt hash')` and then the salt and hash should be accessible in the returned document.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer! I think it's not about username or email naming, I've provided it in custom Fields const, it manages passport to read email as username (I hope it does!). Also, passport-local-mongoose is used in my project. I think it's not the async/sync case, I've tried this already. I added some code to the main question about returning data from logging and registering, maybe there's the problem.

Comment: @KrzysztofBiałk Oh yea I see your extra examples. Have you seen this question on stackoverflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138992/use-email-with-passport-local-previous-help-not-working It looks like the poster is having the same issue you are
I think you have to update your Strategy in order to supply new values for usernameField and passwordField

Comment: I've tried to do solutions from the question you handed me. Unfortunately none of them worked to me, so I'm still stuck with this error. I have pasted my code of the LocalStrategy, it looks good to me and I think that it's not the problem. However, I really do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @KrzysztofBiałk I think we were both going too deep. I bet you'll laugh once you see how easy the solution is. I think Mongoose removes the hash and salt fields from these kinds of queries by default. So to make your query work you just need to type `LogUser.findOne({username: username}, 'username salt hash')` and then the salt and hash should be accessible in the returned document. This was driving me crazy, but I'm glad you asked the question because I learned something about Mongoose.

Comment: Oh my God I knew it's gonna be something silly, thank you so much, I've been struggling with it for so long.

Answer (score 0):

```
        solution for me as below

my User model
    
         const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       password: String,
      salt: String,
    });
    
    
    UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
      if (this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) {
      var salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
      var genHash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(this.password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
      this.salt = salt;
      this.password = genHash;
      next();
    
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    });
    
    
    
    my passport.js file
    
     passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        {
          usernameField: 'email',
          passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, email, password, done) {
          User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
              return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Incorrect email'));
            }
            const isPasswordMatched = user.validPassword(password);
            console.log('isPasswordMatched===',isPasswordMatched)
            if (!isPasswordMatched) {
              return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Incorrect password'));
            }
            return done(null, user);
          });
        }
      ));
```